# Key Vault certificate for AKS Load Balancer

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-aks

Is there any documentation or examples describing how to use a Key Vault certificate for an AKS Ingress Load Balancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no integration between AKS and Keyvault

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#is-azure-key-vault-integrated-with-aks

However, using the above link, you will see that the Azure Key Vault FlexVolume for Kubernetes project enables direct integration from Kubernetes pods to KeyVault secrets.

https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-keyvault-flexvol

Depending on your Ingress, you would normally be able to bring in a TLS cert over a volume / Secret.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-own-tls